# How do I publish an ASP.NET application to the Internet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, blogspot

I created one asp.net web application. Now, can I add that into my blogspot? Or else How to add my webpages into internet?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6dbcb8d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: dotnetspider.com offers free hosting for testing websites.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET websites must be hosted on an IIS server. As such, they can't be run on blogspot or such services. Search for ASP.NET compatible web hosts to host your app.

Comment: @NickT: If you're reading this, don't edit a comment into a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly in nutshell 
Purchase a shared hosting account from online hosting. 
Sign in to your account hosting company provides you.
Go to your control panel
Create site your folder for the blog in IIS. Copy files to it. Setup database if you need to.
set up DNS if you have site, or your hosting company will give you the ip you can access it directly until you purchase domain name.